# RxJava emit first element and buffer others

Tags: rx-java

My observer is overproducing and I need to handle all elements. When I first subscribe I want to receive the element as soon as possible, but I want to buffer others until 
a) the first element is handled 
AND
b) 1 second timeout.

My current implementation is:

```
connectionService.subscribe(request)
.buffer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.flatMap(merger)
.subscribe(...)
```

The "merger" does the work. There are 2 problems with this:

1) the first element will have a 1 second delay too, but it should be available immediatly

2) if the merging takes more than 1 second I receive the next element when the previous is not handled (note that it's only a problem when merging the first element)

Comment: Is this right: You got an observable which will produce elements. Each element must be handled one after another. If the 'handling' of one element takes longer than one second, the next element can be taken and be processed? If it is less than one second, you would like to take the next one and process. Is that about right?

Comment: @HansWurst each element depends on the previous one (they are json patch strings http://jsonpatch.com/). Every element must be handled and in order. The first element is the initial json, so it needs to be computed separately, but the next elements (the json patch elements) can be combined.

Comment: Ok, the first emmited element is the init. json. All following are patches which must be applied to the init. json. It looks like, you would use reduce / scan to apply every emitted patch to initial json and at the end you will get the json with all patches applied. But it could be, that the producer produces faster than you can apply the patches. For this you would use backpressure from rxjava. Is it about right?

Comment: yes, thanks for explaining it much clearer than i did

Comment: Do you use a libary to apply a patch? On the page 'jsonpatch.com' I found zjsonpatch or json-patch?

Comment: I use the com.flipkart.zjsonpatch but it's not related, as there is too much processing that i can't make faster and the observable is so hot it sometimes emits 10+ json patches in a second. So I need an overall solution without taking the calculation time into account.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this (assuming RxJava 1):

```
connectionService.subscribe(request)
.onBackpressureBuffer(...)
.flatMap(merger, 1)
.subscribe(...)
```

Use the parameters of the `onBackpressureBuffer` operator to specify what happens when it overflows.

The `.flatMap(..., 1)` ensures that exactly 1 item is requested from upstream.